# export useState from a components to another components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I am new to React and I have a problem, I would like to get the price(useState) of my "Cards" component to use it in "Wallet".

But I can't find a way to export it.

**This is my Cards.jsx**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Cards = (props) => {

    const [stock, setStock] = useState(props.stock);
    const [price, setPrice] = useState(props.price);

    let buyOneUnit = () => {
        stock > 0 ? setStock(stock - 1) : setStock(0);
    }
    let toDisplayNone = () => {
        return stock === 0 ? "display_none" : ""
    }
    let toDisplay = () => {
        return stock > 0 ? "display_none" : ""
    }

    return (
        <section id={stock > 1 ? "cards" : stock <= 0 ? "cards_red" : "cards_yellow"}>
            <img src={props.img} />
            <h3>{props.name}</h3>
            <h4>{price}</h4>
            <p id={toDisplayNone()}>il reste {stock} produits</p>
            <p id={toDisplay()}>Il n'y a plus de stock !</p>
            <button onClick={buyOneUnit}>boire un {props.name}</button>
        </section>
    )
}

export default Cards;
```

I tried to import price like this but it doesn't work.

**Wallet.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import { price } from "../components/Cards"

const Wallet = () => {

    return (
        <section>
            <h2>My wallet</h2>
            <p>my money : {price}</p>
        </section>
    )
}


export default Wallet;
```

Comment: Check out `redux` or some internal `useContext` and `useReducer` functionality. Redux helps you maintain one state (as the one source of truth) in your application, so you can read and set data in various components across your app.

You can also send the data in props of the component, but that'd require that one of these components is inside another (or they are wrapper in some higher order component that sets the data).

Comment: You should take a look at a term **Lift the state up**. In this term two child components have same parent with a state object.

Comment: Wouldnt really need redux/contex here if they're 1 or 2 level, parent child components. @Thomas, What is the relationship between these components?

Comment: Thanks. I'll try the useContext or useReducer method. Have a nice day.

Comment: How are you using your `Cards` component?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67579736/what-is-the-most-simplest-method-of-updating-components-state-from-another-comp/67579837#67579837