# What is the most simplest method of updating component's state from another component? Lets say components are siblings?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, jsx, setstate

I am trying to create an interactive feature in my web application. Upon selecting an option in one component I want to update state of another component and trigger re-render. How should I go about this.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put both the components inside another component and define the state and setState over there. Now send the setState as a prop to the first component. when you select an option set the state using the setState you have sent. Now, if the second component is using that state as prop, then it will be rerendered.

ParentComponent

- define the state
- FirstComponent takes setState as Prop
- SecondComponent takes the state as Prop

So, in your case, if the second component's state is defined in the parent, we can send its setState as prop to the first component and when a value is selected, change the state in the first component itself. It will change the state present in the parent which will rerender the second component since that state is a prop in second component.

Comment: So basically when we have interactive components, we should make one parent and bulk up the parent's state. Is it design effecient?

Comment: I have seen this type of pattern many times in the projects I have worked on. Not sure if it is design efficient, but it is a simple and a common way.