# How to obtain a value from a file in another file thanks to the store

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have recently started a project in a team of three people. We've been learning some React for that, and when I explained to a friend what I was trying to do, he advised me to try it with Redux, but I'm not quite sure how I'm supposed to proceed.

My goal is to generate a code in an Arrival.js page, depending on a form that the customer filled, based on his first name and the date. I have the right function to generate that code. Now when the customer submits the form, a pop-up shows up, telling him "here's your code: CODE1245" for example. The thing is that this pop-up is a component located in another file named PopUpArrival.js and I can't manage to transfer the code generated in Arrival.js with the form's information.

So I tried to set up a store with reducers and actions, but I can't manage to find any actions that would fit my goals. Am I overthinking it by trying to use Redux? Or is there an easy way to do so? It's been three days and I'm quite lost and demotivated to be honest. Thanks if anyone took the time to read me and I'd be even more grateful if anyone shows up with a solution

Answer (score 0):

If your components have a

- parent-child relationship, then it would be easy to send the code as a prop to the child.
- Sibling relationship, then [What is the most simplest method of updating component's state from another component? Lets say components are siblings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67579736/what-is-the-most-simplest-method-of-updating-components-state-from-another-comp/67579837#67579837)
- Not related at all, there are a lot of ways like cookies, local storage, context, redux, etc.

I guess using redux only for this purpose might be overkill. You can look at contexts in that case.

Answer (score 0):

I think `Redux` maybe an overkill here. You can get this done without `redux` from how it looks. If you can consider the following flow.

Your `Arrival.js` will maintain state for the `first name` and the `date`. Your `PopUpArrival.js` should be a component in itself, which takes whatever text you want to show in `popup` as a `prop`. Based on when you want to trigger the popup logic, you should display the `PopUpArrival` component. I have tried to roughly write some code below which does the same.

```js
const PopUpArrival = (props) => {
  const { textToShow } = props;

  return( 
    <div>{textToShow}</div>;
  );
}

const Arrival = () => {
  // maintains state for both name and date
  const [showPopup, setPopupDisplay] = useState(false);

  const togglePopup = () => {
    setPopupDisplay((currentDisplay) => !currentDisplay);
  }
  
  const getTextToShow = () => {
    return `${name}-{date}`; // whatever logic you have
  }

  return(
    <>
      <button onClick={togglePopup}>
        Submit
      </button>
      {
        showPopup && <PopUpArrival textToShow={getTextToShow()}/>
      }
    </>
  )
}
```